# React Native - Change navigationOptions header components switching tabs

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I have done some research on docs and stackoverflow, cannot find any related post/docs about this.
I using TabNavigator and StackNavigator for my app navigation, I would like to change the navigationOption header components when switching tabs. I have 3 tabs, `Home` , `Live` and `Radio`

Example -
When tab is Home header components is

`<View><ScrollView><GenerateList_1/></ScrollView></View>`

When tab is Live header components is

`<View><ScrollView><GenerateList_2/></ScrollView></View>`

```
const mainNav = TabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen},
  Live: { screen: LiveScreen },
  Radio: { screen: RadioScreen},
} );

export const mainStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: mainNav,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: (
              <View style={styles.topnavscrollview}>
                <View style={{width:300}}>
                  <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                    <GenerateList_1/> <-- Change this when switch to Live tab or others
                  </ScrollView>
                </View>
              </View>
      ),
    },
  },
  Content: { screen: ContentScreen },
});
```

**Current header is share on each tab**